# Getting error when joining the table with the subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to do a left join between two tables with the subquery that I have.

Below is the database and table query for sample data:

```
CREATE SCHEMA `mystore`;

CREATE TABLE `mystore`.`outlet` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

INSERT INTO outlet (id, name) VALUES (1, 'A'),(2, 'B'),(3, 'C');

CREATE TABLE `mystore`.`coupon` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `outlet_id` INT NULL,
  `coupon_code` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `discount` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

INSERT INTO coupon (outlet_id, coupon_code, discount) VALUES (1, 'GET50', 50),(NULL, 'GET10', 10),(3, 'GET20', 20);
```

The following query works to get me the expected result:

```
SELECT `out`.`id`, `coupon_code`, `outlet_id` FROM `outlet` `out`
LEFT JOIN(SELECT `coupon_code`,`outlet_id` FROM `coupon` WHERE FIND_IN_SET('1','1,2,3')) `c` ON `c`.`outlet_id` IS NOT NULL
WHERE `out`.`id` = 1;
```

but instead of passing direct search string value i.e. 1 in the FIND_IN_SET I'm trying to fetch from 'out.id'. When I try using the below query I got an error i.e. Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'out.id' in 'where clause'

```
SELECT `out`.`id`, `coupon_code`, `outlet_id` FROM `outlet` `out`
LEFT JOIN(SELECT `coupon_code`,`outlet_id` FROM `coupon` WHERE FIND_IN_SET(`out`.`id`,'1,2,3')) `c` ON `c`.`outlet_id` IS NOT NULL
WHERE `out`.`id` = 1;
```

What can I do to make this work?
PS - I don't want to declare the variable and use that variable in search string value.

Answer (score 1):

I rewrite your query, try this if this will meet the results you wanted.

```
SELECT `out`.`id`, `coupon_code`, `outlet_id` FROM outlet `out`
LEFT JOIN coupon c ON c.`outlet_id` IS NOT NULL AND FIND_IN_SET(`out`.`id`,'1,2,3')
WHERE `out`.`id`=1;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
    id  coupon_code  outlet_id  
------  -----------  -----------
     1  GET50                  1
     1  GET20                  3
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT `out`.`id`, `coupon_code`, `outlet_id` 
FROM `outlet` `out`
LEFT JOIN LATERAL ( SELECT `coupon_code`,`outlet_id` 
                    FROM `coupon` 
                    WHERE FIND_IN_SET(`out`.`id`,'1,2,3')
                  ) `c` ON `c`.`outlet_id` IS NOT NULL
WHERE `out`.`id` = 1;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=407f995d90eb09b3abfbc1bf1ddc0b1a